# Pentaho table input step goes to idle state

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pdi

I have a similar table structure in two different schema of MySQL. I am trying to get the data from one schema using table input and inserting the same data to a different schema using insert / update step. When I run the ktr, it is going to idle state after reading 1 row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th most probable issue is that you are auto-locking your table. Either the output or the input. The logs won't give you anything.

Start debugging by creating an output table with the same structure as your output table and put a few records in it with a `Table output` (without truncate). When this works, built your use case by incremental improvement. It should take you 3-5 iterations.